# Is it possible to use GKSU from the Dash (Use administrative level from Dash)

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash, gksu

I know I can press ALT+F2 and type for example `gksu nautilus` but I want to be able to use it from Dash. How can I do this?

Comment: WARNING for people who might have came here from Google: By running  Nautilus as root you can really (I mean really) screw up totally. For example, you can accidentally delete necessary boot-files and other people's important stuff.

Unless you're really, really sure about what you're doing, do _not_ elevate your Nautilus window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `Alt + F2` and type `alacarte` and run.  This is the menu editor and will allow you to make a launcher that not only shows up in the Classic Menu but the Dash as well.  Click on add new item and type in `gksu nautilus` for the command,select an icon and give it a name like **Super Nautilus** and click ok.  Now when you click on Dash and start to type nautilus it will show up as one of the Applications

Comment: Awesome man. You just made my life 0.1% easier hehe.

Answer (score 1):

Well I don't think that the Dash allows to pass parameters to an app.
The only thing I can think of is to add gksu to the main menu (in dash type 'main menu')  but it will not accept any option so you will have to enter the name of the app when gksu opens.

At least, that is the default Dash behavior.